# CMake can´t find Boost and its COmponents

Tags: boost, cmake, cmakelists-options

again..

First:

```
Plattform: Windows
Cmake: 3.20 (Clion Bundled)
Kit: Mingw64 (msys2-Mingw64)
Boost Version: 1.69 - 1.77 (from boost.org)
```

Following Situation:

I want to find_package boost via Cmake. Therefor, i downloaded the boost zip, extracted it and set the BOOST_ROOT.
This is my current CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Tester LANGUAGES CXX)
set(TEST_PROJECT ${PROJECT_NAME})

project(Runtime LANGUAGES CXX)
set(RUNTIME_PROJECT ${PROJECT_NAME})

project(Game_Lib LANGUAGES CXX)
set(LIB_PROJECT ${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

#=============================================================== Fetch GoogleTest
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/e2239ee6043f73722e7aa812a459f54a28552929.zip
)
# For Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

#=============================================================== Setup Paths
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(PROJ_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(PROJ_INC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(PROJ_LIBS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(PROJ_TESTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests)
set(PROJ_TST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test)
set(PROJ_SHADES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../TileGameStudio_Editor_Build_Debug/Shipped/Data/InitProj/shaders)

set(ANGLE_INCLUDE_PATH "D:/angle/include")
set(ANGLE_LIBRARY_PATH ${PROJ_LIBS})

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_MIXER REQUIRED SDL2_mixer)
find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
find_package(LuaJIT REQUIRED)
find_package(FLAC REQUIRED)
find_package(OGG REQUIRED)
find_package(THEORA REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/boost")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

#=============================================================== OUTPUT <LIB>_FOUND
if (NOT PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "PKG-CONFIG:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "PKG-CONFIG:   YES - under: ${PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE} >> used to find packages")
endif ()

if (NOT SDL2_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "SDL2:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "SDL2:   YES - under: ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(
            ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(
            ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_DIRS}
            ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif ()

if (NOT FREETYPE_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "freetype2:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "freetype2:   YES - under: ${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build})
    link_directories(${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build})
endif ()

if (NOT LUAJIT_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "LuaJit:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "LuaJit:   YES - under: ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()

if (NOT FLAC_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "FLAC:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "FLAC:   YES - under: ${FLAC_INCLUDE_DIR} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(${FLAC_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${FLAC_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()

if (NOT OGG_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "OGG:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "OGG:   YES - under: ${OGG_INCLUDE_DIR} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(${OGG_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${OGG_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()

if (NOT THEORA_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "THEORA:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "THEORA:   YES - under: ${THEORA_INCLUDE_DIR} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(${THEORA_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${THEORA_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()

if (NOT OPENSSL_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "OpenSSL:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "OpenSSL:   YES - under: ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()

if (NOT BOOST_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost:   NO")
else ()
    message(STATUS "Boost:   YES - under: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} >> included and linked")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
    link_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
endif ()

#=============================================================== Include Directories
include_directories(
        ${PROJ_INC}
        ${PROJ_SRC}
        ${PROJ_LIBS}
        ${PROJ_SHADES}
        ${ANGLE_INCLUDE_PATH}
        ${ANGLE_LIBRARY_PATH}
        gtest/
)

link_directories(
        ${PROJ_INC}
        ${PROJ_SRC}
        ${PROJ_LIBS}
        ${PROJ_SHADES}
        ${ANGLE_INCLUDE_PATH}
        ${ANGLE_LIBRARY_PATH}
        gtest/
)

#=============================================================== Find GLES Libraries
message("Looking for GLES Libraries")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib" ".dll" ".dll.lib")
find_library(D3D_Lib NAMES d3dcompiler_47 PATHS ${PROJ_LIBS} REQUIRED)
find_library(GLES2_Lib NAMES libGLESv2 PATHS ${PROJ_LIBS} REQUIRED)
message("Done: Looking for GLES Libraries")

#=============================================================== Find GTest and GMock Libraries
#find_library(GTEST_LIBRARIES NAMES libgtest_main libgtest libgmock libgmock_main REQUIRED)

#=============================================================== Collect Sources, Tests and Headers
file(GLOB PROJECT_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        ${PROJ_SRC}/*.cpp
        )

file(GLOB PROJECT_TESTS CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        ${PROJ_TST}/*.cpp
        )

file(GLOB PROJECT_HEADERS CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        ${PROJ_INC}/*.h
        )

file(GLOB PROJECT_SHADERS CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        ${PROJ_SHADES}/*.glsl
        )

#=============================================================== Create STATIC Lib of Engine Sources
if (NOT PROJECT_SOURCES)
    message("No Sources available to build static Library!")
else ()
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../TileGameStudio_Editor_Build_Debug/Shipped/Data/InitProj/Libs")
    add_library(${LIB_PROJECT} STATIC ${PROJECT_HEADERS} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
    set_target_properties(${LIB_PROJECT} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "GameLib")
    message("Added Sources to the Library and created it in ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}!")
endif ()

#=============================================================== Build App
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../TileGameStudio_Editor_Build_Debug/Shipped/Data/InitProj")
set(APP_ICON_RESOURCE_WINDOWS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res.rc")
add_executable(${RUNTIME_PROJECT}
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
        ${PROJECT_SHADERS}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res.rc
        )

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../TileGameStudio_Editor_Build_Debug/Shipped/Data/InitProj/Tests")
add_executable(${TEST_PROJECT}
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
        ${PROJECT_SHADERS}
        ${PROJECT_TESTS}
        )

#=============================================================== Set Building Target
set_target_properties(${RUNTIME_PROJECT} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "Game" SUFFIX ".exe")
set_target_properties(${TEST_PROJECT} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "Tests" SUFFIX ".exe")
#=============================================================== Link Libraries
target_link_libraries(${RUNTIME_PROJECT}
        ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARIES}
        ${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES}
        ${LUA_LIBRARY}
        ${GLES2_Lib}
        ${D3D_Lib}
        ${FLAC_LIBRARY}
        ${OGG_LIBRARY}
        ${THEORA_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        )

target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT}
        ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARIES}
        ${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES}
        ${LUA_LIBRARY}
        ${GLES2_Lib}
        ${D3D_Lib}
        ${FLAC_LIBRARY}
        ${OGG_LIBRARY}
        ${THEORA_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        gtest_main
        )
enable_testing()
include(GoogleTest)

#=============================================================== Add GoogleTests
message("")
message("Adding Tests to ${TEST_PROJECT}")
message("")
if (NOT PROJECT_TESTS)
    message("No Tests available!")
else ()
    gtest_add_tests(TARGET ${TEST_PROJECT} TEST_LIST var)
    message("Tests were added to ${TEST_PROJECT}. The List:")
    foreach (X ${var})
        message("-  ${X}")
    endforeach ()
endif ()
message("")
```

And this, results in this Outlog:

```
-- Found Ogg: C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libogg.dll.a
-- Found Ogg: C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libogg.dll.a
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1673 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.77.0;1.77;1.76.0;1.76;1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1674 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1675 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1676 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1678 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1710 ] BOOST_ROOT = "D:/boost"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1711 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1712 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1713 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1714 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1715 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1787 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "D:/boost/include;D:/boost;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1788 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = "boost-1_77_0;boost_1_77_0;boost/boost-1_77_0;boost/boost_1_77_0;boost-1_77;boost_1_77;boost/boost-1_77;boost/boost_1_77;boost-1_76_0;boost_1_76_0;boost/boost-1_76_0;boost/boost_1_76_0;boost-1_76;boost_1_76;boost/boost-1_76;boost/boost_1_76;boost-1_75_0;boost_1_75_0;boost/boost-1_75_0;boost/boost_1_75_0;boost-1_75;boost_1_75;boost/boost-1_75;boost/boost_1_75;boost-1_74_0;boost_1_74_0;boost/boost-1_74_0;boost/boost_1_74_0;boost-1_74;boost_1_74;boost/boost-1_74;boost/boost_1_74;boost-1_73_0;boost_1_73_0;boost/boost-1_73_0;boost/boost_1_73_0;boost-1_73;boost_1_73;boost/boost-1_73;boost/boost_1_73;boost-1_72_0;boost_1_72_0;boost/boost-1_72_0;boost/boost_1_72_0;boost-1_72;boost_1_72;boost/boost-1_72;boost/boost_1_72;boost-1_71_0;boost_1_71_0;boost/boost-1_71_0;boost/boost_1_71_0;boost-1_71;boost_1_71;boost/boost-1_71;boost/boost_1_71;boost-1_70_0;boost_1_70_0;boost/boost-1_70_0;boost/boost_1_70_0;boost-1_70;boost_1_70;boost/boost-1_70;boost/boost_1_70;boost-1_69_0;boost_1_69_0;boost/boost-1_69_0;boost/boost_1_69_0;boost-1_69;boost_1_69;boost/boost-1_69;boost/boost_1_69;boost-1_68_0;boost_1_68_0;boost/boost-1_68_0;boost/boost_1_68_0;boost-1_68;boost_1_68;boost/boost-1_68;boost/boost_1_68;boost-1_67_0;boost_1_67_0;boost/boost-1_67_0;boost/boost_1_67_0;boost-1_67;boost_1_67;boost/boost-1_67;boost/boost_1_67;boost-1_66_0;boost_1_66_0;boost/boost-1_66_0;boost/boost_1_66_0;boost-1_66;boost_1_66;boost/boost-1_66;boost/boost_1_66;boost-1_65_1;boost_1_65_1;boost/boost-1_65_1;boost/boost_1_65_1;boost-1_65_0;boost_1_65_0;boost/boost-1_65_0;boost/boost_1_65_0;boost-1_65;boost_1_65;boost/boost-1_65;boost/boost_1_65;boost-1_64_0;boost_1_64_0;boost/boost-1_64_0;boost/boost_1_64_0;boost-1_64;boost_1_64;boost/boost-1_64;boost/boost_1_64;boost-1_63_0;boost_1_63_0;boost/boost-1_63_0;boost/boost_1_63_0;boost-1_63;boost_1_63;boost/boost-1_63;boost/boost_1_63;boost-1_62_0;boost_1_62_0;boost/boost-1_62_0;boost/boost_1_62_0;boost-1_62;boost_1_62;boost/boost-1_62;boost/boost_1_62;boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost/boost-1_47_0;boost/boost_1_47_0;boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost/boost-1_47;boost/boost_1_47;boost-1_46_1;boost_1_46_1;boost/boost-1_46_1;boost/boost_1_46_1;boost-1_46_0;boost_1_46_0;boost/boost-1_46_0;boost/boost_1_46_0;boost-1_46;boost_1_46;boost/boost-1_46;boost/boost_1_46;boost-1_45_0;boost_1_45_0;boost/boost-1_45_0;boost/boost_1_45_0;boost-1_45;boost_1_45;boost/boost-1_45;boost/boost_1_45;boost-1_44_0;boost_1_44_0;boost/boost-1_44_0;boost/boost_1_44_0;boost-1_44;boost_1_44;boost/boost-1_44;boost/boost_1_44;boost-1_43_0;boost_1_43_0;boost/boost-1_43_0;boost/boost_1_43_0;boost-1_43;boost_1_43;boost/boost-1_43;boost/boost_1_43;boost-1_42_0;boost_1_42_0;boost/boost-1_42_0;boost/boost_1_42_0;boost-1_42;boost_1_42;boost/boost-1_42;boost/boost_1_42;boost-1_41_0;boost_1_41_0;boost/boost-1_41_0;boost/boost_1_41_0;boost-1_41;boost_1_41;boost/boost-1_41;boost/boost_1_41;boost-1_40_0;boost_1_40_0;boost/boost-1_40_0;boost/boost_1_40_0;boost-1_40;boost_1_40;boost/boost-1_40;boost/boost_1_40;boost-1_39_0;boost_1_39_0;boost/boost-1_39_0;boost/boost_1_39_0;boost-1_39;boost_1_39;boost/boost-1_39;boost/boost_1_39;boost-1_38_0;boost_1_38_0;boost/boost-1_38_0;boost/boost_1_38_0;boost-1_38;boost_1_38;boost/boost-1_38;boost/boost_1_38;boost-1_37_0;boost_1_37_0;boost/boost-1_37_0;boost/boost_1_37_0;boost-1_37;boost_1_37;boost/boost-1_37;boost/boost_1_37;boost-1_36_1;boost_1_36_1;boost/boost-1_36_1;boost/boost_1_36_1;boost-1_36_0;boost_1_36_0;boost/boost-1_36_0;boost/boost_1_36_0;boost-1_36;boost_1_36;boost/boost-1_36;boost/boost_1_36;boost-1_35_1;boost_1_35_1;boost/boost-1_35_1;boost/boost_1_35_1;boost-1_35_0;boost_1_35_0;boost/boost-1_35_0;boost/boost_1_35_0;boost-1_35;boost_1_35;boost/boost-1_35;boost/boost_1_35;boost-1_34_1;boost_1_34_1;boost/boost-1_34_1;boost/boost_1_34_1;boost-1_34_0;boost_1_34_0;boost/boost-1_34_0;boost/boost_1_34_0;boost-1_34;boost_1_34;boost/boost-1_34;boost/boost_1_34;boost-1_33_1;boost_1_33_1;boost/boost-1_33_1;boost/boost_1_33_1;boost-1_33_0;boost_1_33_0;boost/boost-1_33_0;boost/boost_1_33_0;boost-1_33;boost_1_33;boost/boost-1_33;boost/boost_1_33"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1803 ] location of version.hpp: D:/boost/boost/version.hpp
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1843 ] Boost_VERSION = "106900"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1844 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.69.0"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1845 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "106900"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1846 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1847 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "69"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1848 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1849 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1873 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1874 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-mgw112" (guessed)
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1910 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1988 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1992 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1993 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2053 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "D:/boost/lib;D:/boost/stage/lib;D:/boost/lib;D:/boost/../lib;D:/boost/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2054 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "D:/boost/lib;D:/boost/stage/lib;D:/boost/lib;D:/boost/../lib;D:/boost/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-mgw112-mt-1_69;boost_filesystem-mgw112-mt;boost_filesystem-mgw112-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_69;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-mgw112-mt-d-1_69;boost_filesystem-mgw112-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mgw112-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_69;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
CMake Error at D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem) (found version "1.69.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  D:/CLion/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:53 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Yeahi..

I searched myself through the Net for 3 Days now and stumbled accros different approaches to fix that..

From, building the libs, to installing thing.. doing stuff and other stuff.. and so on.. i don´t really know what i´ve done there, cause the Manuals and Fixes are more Cryptic than logic to me as Hobby programmer...

I changed the FindBoost.cmake to an updated one, supporting Boost 1.77.. tried to set Hinbt Paths like BOOST_INCLUDEDIR and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR.. nothing changed anything..

I tried Boost Versions: 1.77.0, 1.76.0, 1.69.0 (current)

So..  i´ve no clue what i can do more, to make it possible to link boost to my project...

I hope someone can help me out here..

Edit:
Sry Guys.. but..  i´m really new to this stuf...

I bootstraped boost with gcc as parameter and invoked b2 inside the boost directory..

Now i´ve a bin.v2
+
Got the messages:

```
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
    D:\boost
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
    D:\boost\stage\lib
```

Done by:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/boost")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "D:/boost")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "D:/boost/stage/lib")
```

before find_package

Still get

```
Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem) (found version "1.77.0")
```

:(

Comment: As you could guess from the variable name, `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE` contains the list of directories (separated with semicolon), where Boost libraries are searched. And variable `FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE` contains exact names of libraries. Do you have given libraries under given directories? Or do you have under given directories other library with `filesystem` in its name?

Comment: uhm.. what? I just extracted boost and set the root.. don't know what exactly you mean .  I've no other Libs with name filename on my system. just libGLES 2, libEGL and d3d_compiler47

Comment: I mean that you need to find in the output lines contained `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE` and `FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE`, interpret other content of that lines as I have described above, and search (by yourself) a library among the Boost libraries which you have extracted from the archive.

Comment: I don't know, if the header only libraries can be included without installing boost, but at least for the shared lib version as of boost 1.74 you'd need to use the boost build tool build & to install the whole thing to a local directory which should put the config scripts for boost in the right place. (i.e. you just need to add the directory you installed to to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`)

Comment: @Tsyvarev
I´ve libraries in the boost/stage/lib Location..  But they all start with "libboost..."  and not "boost.."  as the FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG wants them to...

Comment: The `lib` prefix is not a problem. The problem is that **name** of the library file is different than expected one. What is the **exact name** of the library file which you **actually have**?

Comment: libboost_filesystem-mgw11-x64-1_77

Comment: As you can find from the output,, CMake searches the files with `mgw112-mt` suffix, which [means](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) MinGW 11.2 with multithreading. What you have is `mgw11-x64`, which means MinGW 11 for x86-64 architecture. I don't know whether given toolsets are compatible.